# How can I get BeautifulSoup running within another for loop?

Tags: python, html, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm currently trying to put together an article scraper for a website, but I'm running into an issue that I don't know how to solve. This is the code:

```
import newspaper
from newspaper import Article
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from datetime import datetime, timezone
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

urls = open("urls_test.txt").readlines()

final_df = pd.DataFrame()

for url in urls:
    article = newspaper.Article(url="%s" % (url), language='en')
    article.download()
    article.parse()
    article.nlp()

    # scrape html part
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
    results = soup.find(id="main-content")
    texts = results.find_all("div", class_="component article-body-text")
    paragraphs = []
    for snippet in texts:
        paragraphs.append(str(snippet))
    CLEANR = re.compile('<.*?>')
    def remove_html(input):
        cleantext = re.sub(CLEANR, '', input)
        return cleantext
    paragraphs_string = ' '.join(paragraphs)
    paragraphs_clean = remove_html(paragraphs_string)
    #

    temp_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Title', 'Authors', 'Text', 'Summary', 'published_date', 'URL'])

    temp_df['Authors'] = article.authors
    temp_df['Title'] = article.title
    temp_df['Text'] = paragraphs_clean
    temp_df['Summary'] = article.meta_description
    publish_date = article.publish_date
    publish_date = publish_date.replace(tzinfo=None)
    temp_df['published_date'] = publish_date
    temp_df['URL'] = article.url

    final_df = pd.concat([final_df, temp_df], ignore_index=True)

final_df.to_excel('Telegraph_test.xlsx')
```

My problem appears in the *#scrape html part*. Both codes (main code without the *#scrape html part* and only the *#scrape html part*) run fine on their own. More specifically, the code as a whole runs until line `results = soup.find(id="main-content")` (returning the `results` variable as a `bs4.element.Tag` containing the scraped material), but as it continues the `results` variable turns into `NoneType`. This is the error message I get:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing any of the urls and structure of HTML I would say that there is one without an element using `id="main-content"` as attribute - So you should always check if the element you are looking for is available:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
results = soup.find(id="main-content")
if results:
    text = ' '.join([e.get_text(strip=True) for e in results.find_all("div", class_="component article-body-text")])
else:
    text = ''
```

There is no need for your `remove_html()` simply use [`.get_text()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) to extract the text from your element/s.

Comment: Except that there's no whitespace between the paragraphs in the final `text` string, this seems to be working well, thank you! However, now the next problem is that the loop doesn't work, because only the text of the the last url (in the urls_test.txt) is saved to the final xlsx file. (I took out the rest of the *#scrape html part* and changed the line `temp_df['Text'] = paragraphs_clean` to `temp_df['Text'] = text` accordingly.)